The closure of finite rank operators between a Banach space and a Hilbert space is the collection of compact rank operators
Let $B$ be a Banach space and $H$ a Hilbert space. I was asked to prove that the closure of $\mathcal{L}_F(B,H)$, the collection of finite-rank operators, is $\mathcal{L}_C(B,H)$, the collection of compact operators.
If $H$ is separable, then it has a countable orthonormal basis and we can find orthogonal projections $P_n$ on the finite-dimensional space $\operatorname{Span}\{e_1,\cdots, e_n\}$. Let $T\in\mathcal{L}_C(B,H)$, it's not hard to show that $P_n\circ T\rightarrow T$.
But here $H$ might not be separable, I don't think the same method works. Are there some alternative ways to show the density?
Thanks a lot!

You can reduce to the separable case by noting that a compact operator has separable image. There is probably a post on this site somewhere answering your question

@leoli1 Thank you!

You can take the answer here and apply it with $p=2$ combined with the result that every Hilbert space is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell^{2}(I)$ for some set $I$. Note that in the Hilbert space case, the Schauder basis and the projections associated to that Schauder basis will be the orthonormal basis and the orthogonal projections associated to that orthonormal basis respectively.
